# How can I find figure out why a machine has consistently 70%+ CPU usage?

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, macintosh

My machine (Macbookpro, Archlinux) has consistently a CPU at 70%+, yet I have no clue why. This doesn't happen on MacOS, only on Linux.

Using `htop`, I can see no program using more than 2% of CPU. Even without X and after killing every running process I could find, the CPU usage is still at 70%+.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be some crazy interrupt on Macbook pros. http://loicpefferkorn.net/2015/01/arch-linux-on-macbook-pro-retina-2014-with-dm-crypt-lvm-and-suspend-to-disk/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use nmon instead of htop.
The reason for it might be a program, that has high amount of HDD traffic, so that the CPU isn't actually used, but waiting for device sync. Or maybe it isn't actually a processes but a old/damaged HDD. In nmon this is showed seperated in the CPU usage. I don't know if htop does.